# libGDX- How to render a mesh

Tags: java, libgdx, mesh

I'm having trouble in understanding libgdx Mesh and Shader class..

Let's say I have a polygon that I want to render it with a texture, repeatable.

How can I do that? I didn't say any good tutorials about meshes..
I've read this
https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/OpenGLShader

But can't understand much things..

There it is

```
 mesh = new Mesh(true, 4, 6, VertexAttribute.Position(), VertexAttribute.  ColorUnpacked(), VertexAttribute.TexCoords(0));
mesh.setVertices(new float[] 
{-0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
-0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0});
mesh.setIndices(new short[] {0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0});
```

How should I put my polygon vertices there?
Do I have to use earclippingtriangulator ?